# How to use NetBeans's JProgressBar?

Tags: swing, netbeans, jprogressbar

I am using Netbeans gui, the fast easy drag and drop, lets say a created a JButton, named it "Start", I added an event (ActionPerformed) for this JButton, so I get the following method

```
private void JButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)     
{                                             
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}
```

Then I added a JProgressBar, I want this progressbar to start when I click on this button, and be able to control its speed...etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot directly set it's speed, you just have to set it's value. Read the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JProgressBar.html) for details. BTW JProgressBar is not really Netbeans specific, it is standard swing gui toolkit.